# Getting error when trying to delete part file

Tags: raspbian

I get an error saying "Error when getting information for file" whenever I try to delete or do anything else such as cut or rename a file I have. I'm thinking it might have something to do with the fact it ends with "mp4.part-Frag105". I have already tried deleting it in terminal. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

> A PART file is a partially downloaded file from the Internet used for downloads that are in progress or have been stopped. Some PART files can be resumed at a later time using the same program that started the download. PART files are typically used by Mozilla Firefox and several file transfer programs, such as Go!Zilla, eMule, and the discontinued eDonkey program.
>
> Source: https://fileinfo.com/extension/part

Chances are, the OS still has the file open for writing to, which may be why you can't delete, cut, or rename it.